# Adapter to turn wired USB keyboard wireless?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, keyboard, bluetooth, wired

I've got a wired USB keyboard that I really like. I know it is a long shot, but is there a way to turn it into a wireless (maybe even Bluetooth) keyboard through some sort of adapter or hack?

Comment: You'd need some sort of wireless USB hub, I suspect.  Unfortunately, they're bulky and expensive.

Comment: you could try hacking some ardiuno project

Comment: @DanielRHicks Where can you actually get them? Searching for them just turns up regular USB hubs, USB extenders, and suchlike.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

depending how good you are with a soldering iron and circuit design you might be able to make a Frankenstein keyboard by sacrificing another wireless keyboard, but the end result probably would not be pretty. so unless you are **very** attached to this keyboard it i doubt it would be worth it.

Answer (score 16):

I developed a wireless converter for wired USB keyboards since I never saw this convertor except Bluetooth adapters. I wanted to make a wireless converter for fast pairing.

I created a converter using USB host MCU (pic24fj128gb106) and RF IC (nRF24L01).
I built a USB dongle using RF IC, the built in MCU and USB controller (nRF24LU1P).

You can check [a demonstration of the wireless converter](http://youtu.be/O04FtcfSgF0) on YouTube.

This converter is not for sale, I just made for my requirement. I tested it using a wired USB keyboard.

Comment: This is great commentary, but not an answer IMO.

Comment: @CarlB The OP was asking if there was a way to turn a wired keyboard into a wireless one, even through a hack, which this answer is about. So we can let it stay.

Comment: @slhck - I can see your point. My challenge was/is - content, "here is what I did", but not "here is how you can do it" or "here is where you can get one"..

Comment: I am sorry I can not understood about this site. I just remain my experience. If my answer was not enough then please delete away.

Comment: @Heesoo, can you provide schematics / hex (or source code) for your project so that we can duplicate it?

Answer (score 8):

Go to handheldsci.com and find their Bluetooth Keyboard Adapter (http://handheldsci.com/kb). I have one and it works great. Very handy and unique device.

Comment: http://handheldsci.com/kb

Comment: This looks like it still needs a USB host for power, possibly a USB power pack would work?

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example of a ['wireless USB hub'](http://www.iogear.com/product/GUWH204KIT/).  Bulky, but if you *REALLY* like the keyboard it might work for you. :)

Note: this one doesn't say it supports keyboard specifically, and probably won't work in the BIOS, or with anything other than Windows.

Comment: Actually, since there's a USB receiver on the computer side, there's no reason it shouldn't just function like any other USB hub in both BIOS and on the computer side. I don't have one myself but this is how they seem to work in practice; i.e - the wireless part is invisible to the computer.

Comment: It doesn't look that bulky.  It says it's EOL though, I've been looking for a while and can't find another like it. -- All the wireless hubs I find don't have the USB receiver, and instead work in software somehow..., which is not what I want.

Answer (score -1):

Officially, no, not really, but you can have a look at [this article](http://courses.cit.cornell.edu/ee476/FinalProjects/s2003/lph2/WirelessKybd/index.html) to see if it is something that might be possible for the model of keyboard you have.